# Little problem with \tkzMarkRightAngle

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tkz-euclide

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt}]
\path
  (30:5) node [label=below right:$v_i\in M_2$,yshift={5pt}]{} coordinate (A)
  (30:7) coordinate (a)
  (-20:5) node [label=above right:$u_i\in M_1$,yshift={-10pt}]{} coordinate (B)
  (-20:7) coordinate (b)
  (0:0) node {} coordinate(P);

\path
  (0:0) node {}
coordinate(W)
  (90:4) node [label=left:$w_i$]{}
coordinate (Z)
  (90:6) coordinate (z);

\node (Q) at ($(P)!(A)!(B)$) {};
\node (R) at ($(P)!(B)!(A)$) {};

\draw[<->]  (P) -- (A);
\draw (P) -- (a);
\draw  (P) -- (b);
\draw[->] (P) -- (B);
\draw[->] (P) -- (Z);
\draw (P) -- (z);

\draw[purple!70!black,dashed] (A) -- (Q);
\draw[green!70!black] (B) -- (R);
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,Q,P)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(B,R,P)

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75cm,color=cyan,label=$\theta$](B,P,A);
\end{tikzpicture} }
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

As you can see, the squares for right angles isn't appears good. There are something that I make bad? Any option or libraries is not necessary?

PD: I read [A right-angle mark not displayed properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241226/a-right-angle-mark-not-displayed-properly?s=4%7C2.3538) but the problem continues making `%[dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt}]`.

PD: I have another packages but it has nothing to do with this graphic.

PD: If some package is missing, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `\node`s for `Q` and `R`; use `\coordinate`s instead; a `\node` has an `inner sep` and `outer sep` which cause the problem.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt}]
\path
  (30:5) node [label=below right:$v_i\in M_2$,yshift={5pt}]{} coordinate (A)
  (30:7) coordinate (a)
  (-20:5) node [label=above right:$u_i\in M_1$,yshift={-10pt}]{} coordinate (B)
  (-20:7) coordinate (b)
  (0:0) node {} coordinate(P);

\path
  (0:0) node {}
coordinate(W)
  (90:4) node [label=left:$w_i$]{}
coordinate (Z)
  (90:6) coordinate (z);

\coordinate (Q) at ($(P)!(A)!(B)$);
\coordinate (R) at ($(P)!(B)!(A)$);

\draw[<->]  (P) -- (A);
\draw (P) -- (a);
\draw  (P) -- (b);
\draw[->] (P) -- (B);
\draw[->] (P) -- (Z);
\draw (P) -- (z);

\draw[purple!70!black,dashed] (A) -- (Q);
\draw[green!70!black] (B) -- (R);
\tkzMarkRightAngle(P,Q,A)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(P,R,B)

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75cm,color=cyan,label=$\theta$](B,P,A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As a side note, since you are loading `tkz-euclide` and using some of its features, you could use the package commands and features for most of the things you are doing directly with TikZ; for example, instead of

```
\coordinate (Q) at ($(P)!(A)!(B)$);
\coordinate (R) at ($(P)!(B)!(A)$);
```

you can use

```
\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto P--B](A)
\tkzGetPoint{Q}
\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto P--A](B)
\tkzGetPoint{R}
```